# Deployment issue with knowledge page layout required fields

Tags: deployment, knowledge, ant, lightning-knowledge

I have custom field on Knowledge object. And made that custom field as required on Knowledge page layout. When I deploy using ant from one sand box to another that custom field is not effected(means it still not mandatory filed) on knowledge page layout. In meta data I have added 'Required' tag manually but I could not deploy it.

```
<layoutSections>
        <customLabel>true</customLabel>
        <detailHeading>true</detailHeading>
        <editHeading>true</editHeading>
        <label>Details</label>
        <layoutColumns>

            <layoutItems>
                <field>Cfield1__c</field>
            </layoutItems>
            <layoutItems>
                <field>CField2__c</field>
            </layoutItems>
        </layoutColumns>
        <style>OneColumn</style>
    </layoutSections>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to description in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm#LayoutItem) :

> Note: KAVs, attempting to explicitly specify UiBehavior will result in an exception.

This means that field `<behaviour>` tag is not allowed in Knowledge Article layout metadata.

There seems to be some limitation and there is also an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003aTQQAY) about this.

You could consider deploying this change as a manual step.

Comment: Thanks for the update